# Возможно ли изменить системное приложение?

Tags: android

Добрый день, есть системное android приложение которое использует камеру телефона REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO, возможно ли добраться до его исходного кода и соответственно как если это возможно ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого вам потребуется root-доступ.
При помощи root, Достаньте APK-файл системмного приложения, декомпилируйте его, и читайте его исходники сколько пожелаете.
Я предполагаю, что вы столкнетесь с другой проблемой - у системмных приложений есть разрешения, которые доступны только для системмных приложений.

---

UPD
Точно, на чтение открыта. Поэтому, рут доступ в общем не нужен

Comment: уточню, что саму apk можно получить без рут доступа. Папка `data/app/<package>[.<num>]` открыта.